# How to tell what's the MIME type according to the file?

Tags: android, file, types, android-intent, mime

Is there any elegant way (not just `if ("fileExt".compareTo(".mp3")) {MIME_TYPE = "audio/*"}`) to learn programatically the MIME type that should be put into an intent, with which I have to open the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

well it does the same as your if statement but is slightly more elegant

Use the MimeTypeMap class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediaStore to find the mime type:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#MIME_TYPE